# Connecting to the Integration Services on "srvrname" failed : "The specified service does not exist as an installed service."

Tags: sql, ssis, ssms

I have a clean installation of SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Edition SP1 on a fresh Win Server 2012R2 Standard Edition. Added all the features and for some reasons I am not able to login to the SSIS service installed using SSMS. SSMS is also a separate installation (latest version ssms 16.5.3). I am not able to see the SSIS server installed even though I can clearly start and stop it using the configuration manager. Some were saying to run the ssms as administrator and that didnt help. Your help is appreciated. See images for details.[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you see the SSIS service running in the services applet? (run services.msc)

Comment: Yes. It is up and running as well.

Comment: Actually I beleive the the SSIS service is a 'legacy' thing. In SQl 2016 you create an integration services catalog to hold your packages, logs etc. and you connect to that. You don't connect to the SSIS service anymore.'. Some info here: https://auntkathisql.com/2015/01/15/what-is-the-ssis-catalog/

Answer (score 4):

[This is documented as a defect, but it isn't.](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2779968/ssms-2016-error-connecting-to-integration-services-on-a-sql-server-2008-r2-instance)  Use SSMS 16.x for SQL 2016 and for SQL 2017 use SSMS 17.x.  Also note that 16.x will not work with SQL 2014, as this is by design.  [Setting up and using SSISDB is what Microsoft wants; look for the notes in the box at the provided link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/integration-services-service-ssis-service#manage-the-service).

This information came from our Microsoft SQL representative, [though its posted as well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/integration-services-service-ssis-service#manage-the-service).  [Click here to download 16.5.3 from Microsoft.](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=840946)

Answer (score 1):

The SSIS Service is not used in SQL 2016

It's a legacy service, only needed in a very specific case - if you have older versions of packages that you haven't upgraded, that you need to store in MSDB.

It is replaced by the SSISDB and SSIS catalog

Why do you think you need to connect to it?

See here for more info:

https://auntkathisql.com/2015/01/15/what-is-the-ssis-catalog/

Comment: Downvoter please explain. Is there some statement here that you disagree with?

Comment: Exactly what I needed. "Why do you think you need to connect to it?" --> for me, simple answer: that's what I used to do years ago, and it didn't occur to me that it might have changed.